# Google Apps for Work - Drive activity events API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been playing with the Google Admin-SDK and the Drive Activity Events API. I was wondering if there is any way I can get activity events from a Google Apps for Work account. I see that I can get full reports through Google Apps Unlimited accounts, but only Login Activity Events for Apps for Work.

Is there any way I can request full reports through the API for Apps for Work accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can request through '*Reports API Drive Activity*' apply to Google Apps Unlimited accounts.

Code below is a sample request to get a report on all of customer's Drive events.
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive?customerId=ABC123xyz

Here's were I found my answer:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive

Comment: That's for Google Apps Unlimited, however I want to get activities for Google Apps for Work. I am requesting that but the response is empty

Comment: the link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive says that you can only make those calls for Google Apps Unlimited accounts. Do you know where can you make those calls for Google Apps for Work?

Comment: any idea on how to solve this [tag:google-drive-sdk] ?